# HTML5 video doesn't load the first 1-2 seconds of video

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have a video in a `<video>` tag on my site with an .mp4 source.

On desktop firefox, it works well. 
But with Chrome, if I try to rewind the video to the beginning, it starts from ~2 seconds of video.

On mobile devices, doesn't load the first ~2 seconds of the video, tried with firefox and chrome.

Anybody has some idea what's wrong with it?

thanks

Comment: What is the length of the video ?

Comment: it's 10 seconds

Comment: and what is the video element width ?

Comment: width="100%" if i try to embed where i want.

if i just load the video like http://xy.com/path/to/video.mp4 there is no width.

Answer (score 0):

**The cause:**

Your problem is the `<video>` element `width` propery versus the length of your video. Since your video is only 10 seconds, the scrollbar in the `<video>` element cannot jump to the exact beginning, since some browsers segment the scrollbar according to the ratio between the `<video>` element's `width` and the length of the video incorrectly.

**Possible solution:**

Add Javascript to rewind the movie to the 0'th second. You can use the `onseeked` event and check if the user tried seeking to the beginning of the movie, and then set the video's current time to 0 - which is the exact beginning.

Example:

```
 var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

 video.onseeked = function() {
    if (video.currentTime <= 2)
        video.currentTime = 0;
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Every videos which shorter, than 15 seconds has this issue. Unfortunately your solution isn't working. video.load() solves the problem, but it loads the video every time, so i think i won't use it. So I'm trying on...but big thanks for the cause

Comment: Why not use my solution though? It should do the exact thing you wanted...

Comment: The video is a slideshow from 5 images, it changes every 2 seconds. Your code somehow starts from the second image which is at 2 secs, don't know why.