# A video is not playing on my local website

Tags: html, css, video, attributes

My 2 second video not playing, but I've tried with 10 second and it worked perfectly. Why is that? Does HTML don't play videos that are shorter than 1-2 second?

It's only an image, help please.

```
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline> 
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Look at this >>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254490/html5-video-doesnt-load-the-first-1-2-seconds-of-video

Answer (score 0):

mistake in your code.

try with playsinline

```
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted playsinline> 
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video